# UIPasteboard pasteboardWithName not working in IOS7.1

Tags: ios, ios7.1, uipasteboard

I have to transfer data from one APP to another. when i transfer data **at first time using paste board its working fine**, but in **second time i am getting nil data from paste board**.This problem is **only happening in IOS7.1 device**,its ok in all other devices. its a strange thing.

My code as follows.

```
// set Data
UIPasteboard* pasteBoard = [UIPasteboard pasteboardWithName:@"TEST" create:YES];

if(item == nil)
{
     NSLog(@"** Set data is nil");
}

if(pasteBoard)
{
    [pasteBoard setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:item]];
}


// Get Data
UIPasteboard* pasteboard = [UIPasteboard pasteboardWithName:@"TEST" create:NO];
NSDictionary* migrateInfo = nil;

if(pasteboard != nil && pasteboard.items.count > 0){
       migrateInfo = [pasteboard.items objectAtIndex:0];
       DEV_LOG(@"** Pasteboard have data");
  }
```

When i transfer data second time, **i am getting nil value as migrateInfo object.**

Comment: Did you set the property `persistent` to YES? Just like this `pasteBoard.persistent = YES`. You may check out the documentation of UIPasteBoard [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPasteboard_Class/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIPasteboard/persistent)

Answer (score 0):

I made two changes in my code after that its worked.

1)After i read data from pasteboeard removed pasteboardData

**Pasteboard data can be removed** using method **removePasteboardWithName.**

[UIPasteboard removePasteboardWithName:PASTE_BOARD_NAME];

2)I used **setValue function instead of SetItems function.**
 (To put objects—such as NSString, NSArray, NSDictionary, NSDate, NSNumber, UIImage, or NSURL objects—on the pasteboard, use the setValue:forPasteboardType: method.)